# React перемещение дива удерживая ЛКМ

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть див и когда я его перемещаю удерживая левую кнопку мыши все работает за исключение одного, то что когда я виду мышкой быстро с него слетает курсор и он перестает двигаться, а если див и вовсе маленького размера, то это и вовсе нереально его перемещать, так я это все к чему можно ли сделать так что когда я удерживаю на диве курсов и перемещаю его курсор оставаться на диве или сделать так что бы он не выходил за див когда я удерживаю ЛКМ

Вот мой код  [КОД](https://codesandbox.io/s/moving-div-by-x-and-y-prjf2t?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Перемещение фигуры меньше, чем перемещение курсора, поэтому, он и выходит за границу удерживаемой фигуры. Могу предложить костыльный вариант решения - в методе `onMouseMove` умножая значения `event.movementX` и `event.movementY` на 2 и тогда перемещение фигуры будет примерно соответствовать требуемому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При активации `pressed` вешайте обработчики `mousemove` и `mouseup` на `window`, которые будет отслеживать перемещение и отжатие мыши.

(см. комментарии ниже)

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);

const appStyle = {
  fontFamily: "sansSerif",
  textAlign: "center",
  userSelect: "none",
};

const inputCStyle = {
  width: "100px",
  height: " 30px",
  fontSize: "20px",
  position: "relative",
  top: "0",
  left: "0",
  display: "flex",
  cursor: "pointer",
  background: "#343434",
  marginTop: "30px",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
};

const h1Style = {
  display: "block",
  margin: "0",
  padding: "0",
  fontSize: "24px",
  marginLeft: "20px",
  paddingRight: "10px",
  marginTop: "35px",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
};

const quickAndDirtyStyle = {
  width: "250px",
  height: "250px",
  transform: "rotate(0deg)",
  borderRadius: "140px",
  background: "rgb(74, 255, 147)",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  fontSize: "20px",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
};

function App() {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  /*зачем использовать ref, если вы и так управляете позицией через стейт, просто записывайте её напрямую в prop style компонента (см. в компонент)
  const ref = React.useRef();*/

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /*если нажат, вешаем обработчики перемещения, а также обработчик отжатия*/
    if (pressed) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", togglePressed);
    }

    return () => {
      /*не забываем обработчики удалять*/
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", togglePressed);
    };
  }, [position, pressed]);

  /*ваш mousemove*/
  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    const x = position.x + event.movementX;
    const y = position.y + event.movementY;
    setPosition({ x, y });
  };
  /*переключение нажатия*/
  const togglePressed = () => {
    setPressed((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    setPosition((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [type]: e.target.valueAsNumber };
    });
  };

  const inputCP = React.useRef();
  const editItemCP = () => {
    inputCP.current.select();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={appStyle}>
      <div className="map" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <h1 style={h1Style}>X</h1>
        <input
          style={inputCStyle}
          className="inputC"
          type="number"
          value={position.x}
          ref={inputCP}
          onClick={editItemCP}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "x")}
        />
        <h1 style={h1Style}>Y</h1>
        <input
          style={inputCStyle}
          className="inputC"
          type="number"
          value={position.y}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "y")}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "50%",
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className={pressed ? "box_0-active" : "box-0"}
          /*ref={ref} уже не нужен*/
          /*здесь позиция из стейта*/
          style={{
            ...quickAndDirtyStyle,
            marginLeft: `${position.x}px`,
            marginTop: `${position.y}px`,
          }}
          /*onMouseMove={onMouseMove} вешаем на window*/
          onClickCapture={() => setPressed(false)}
          onMouseDown={togglePressed}
          /*onMouseUp={() => setPressed(false)} вешаем на window
          onMouseLeave={() => setPressed(false)} не нужен*/
        >
          <p>{pressed ? "Dragging..." : "Press to drag"}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #343434;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103.9vw;
  background-color: #343434;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( #ffffff10 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%), repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff10 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.box-0 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
}

.box-0:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #4aff93;
  cursor: grab;
}

.box-0:focus::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #4aff93;
  cursor: grab;
}

.box_0-active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
}

.box_0-active:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #4aff93;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.box_0-active:focus::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #4aff93;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```